# Aliases in fractional factorial designs

Tags: logistic, experiment-design

I am looking at using a [fractional factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design) design in order to reduce the number of treatment runs for an experiment involving a binary outcome. The [idea](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/206-2012.pdf) is to create the design, then, since this is a marketing application and not an engineering one, use some number of replicants per treatment combination (say 20,000 in each) and analyze the result in a logistic regression.

I am using the [package FRF2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FrF2/index.html) for fractional factorials. Say I have a 2^8 factorial and wish to be able to see the main effects and a selected group of second order interactions:

```
#now lets say we want to be able to read all the main effects A-H and also a couple of the 2nd order interactions we *think* will be important/large
# specifically, lets say we want AB, AC, AD, FH and GH

dMod3<-FrF2(nfactors=8,default.levels = c("-", "+"),estimable= c( "AB","AC","AD","FH","GH") , clear = FALSE , res3 = FALSE)
aliasprint(dMod3)
design.info(dMod3)
```

This yields a design with 16 "runs", which will each receive 20,000 replicants.
The aliasing is as follows:

```
$fi2
[1] AB=CF=DG=HE AC=BF=DH=GE AD=BG=CH=FE AE=BH=CG=DF AF=BC=DE=GH AG=BD=CE=FH
[7] AH=BE=CD=FG
```

If I simulate the responses (1 or 0) to these 20000*16 cases, I can use a logistic regression to analyze the experiment. What I am confused by is that I can fit main effects and interactions that are supposedly confounded, for example I can fit

```
glm(Y~A+B+A:B+C:F).
```

even though AB and CF are confounded.

**Questions:**

1. Is it because I have replication that I can fit this model?
2. What is the implication of fitting such a model?
3. Is a fractional factorial using this situation (like the linked paper) nonsensical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that one can fit `glm(Y~A+B+A:B+C:F)` , but not a model that includes all the main effects and both interactions (the aliased ones will not be estimable).

This works: `glm(Y~A+B+A:B+C:F)`
This works: `glm(Y~A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+A:B)`

This will not return an estimate for C:F  `glm(Y~A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+A:B+C:F)`

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            B            C            D            E  
  -4.518337    -0.059187     0.027127    -0.078180     0.009838     0.052071  
          F            G            H          A:B          C:F  
  -0.043647    -0.034549     0.020001     0.082830           NA
```